# No such method is executed using Test NG annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

// Login.java file, i have executed this file in which i have given TestG Annotations but result shows no method is executed.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login {

public static FirefoxDriver _webBrowser;
public String _url;

@Test(priority = 1, enabled = true)
public Login(FirefoxDriver driver, String url) {
    _webBrowser = driver;
    _url = url;
}



@Test(priority = 2)
private boolean openBrowser() {
    boolean isSuccess = false;
    try {
        _webBrowser.manage().window().maximize();
        _webBrowser.get(_url);
    _webBrowser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        isSuccess = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return isSuccess;
} 

    @Test(priority = 3)
public boolean doLogin(String username, String password) {
    boolean isSuccess = false;
    try {
        if (openBrowser()) {

    Login module = new Login(_webBrowser,    "http://180.211.114.147:97/Account/Login");
            module.doLogin("devrana","dev123");

            _webBrowser.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(username);
            _webBrowser.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(password);
            _webBrowser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120,      TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            _webBrowser.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).submit();

            String tmp = _webBrowser.getCurrentUrl();
            if (tmp.equals("http://180.211.114.147:97/#/app/dashboard"))
                System.out.println("Login success!!");
            else
                System.out.println("Fail to login..");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return isSuccess;
}   

}
```

console output generated while execute this code and result in Test NG shows Test 1/1 Methods:0 (194ms)

```
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@39ed3c8d: 1 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 7 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@515f550a: 35 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@5d22bbb7: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@1c4af82c: 126 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@4361bd48: 20 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using return in @Test methods. In testng we use Assertions to cross check instead of returning pass or fail Boolean values.

```
 public class Example {


public static WebDriver driver;

@Test(priority=1)
public void GoStack(){
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Stack Overflow"); //if it is pass then GoStack test will pass
}


@Test(priority=2)
public void LoginTitle(){
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.className("login-link")).click();
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Log In - Stack Overflow");
}

@Test(priority=3)
public void Dashborad(){
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("email id here");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password here");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit-button")).click();
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "title after login here");
}

 }
```

Please refer [testng](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) documentation for further details. You can use @BeforeTest to perform some actions like opening browser means sort of pre-conditions and also we can use @AfterTest for post conditions like closing browser etc..

Thank You,
Murali